Help Finding Part for High Gear Reduction
I am looking to gear down a small two-stroke engine about 36 times, from over 9000 RPM to about 180-240ish RPM. How should I do this? I would like to prioritize a low cost primarily, as well as a second priority of efficiency. The engine I am using does not have much torque, so it is important that there are minimal losses. That being said, this is for a small project that does not deserve excessive costs. Is what I'm looking for feasible, or should I try to find an engine better suited for the project? I would prefer to keep my current setup if at all possible. I would also appreciate if you could suggest a way to obtain this part, whether it be 3D printing, buying online, or having it fabricated (or something else entirely).
Thanks!

Hydraulic pump and motor - most flexible...

Worm gears out of all gearboxes have an awful efficiency, and it gets worse with higher reduction ratio. "Awful" does not mean 90% instead of 99%, for a reduction ratio of 36 we are talking about an efficiency of 40 to 50%

Two stages of 6:1 planetary gears (sun and planet gears the same size) could be both compact and reasonably efficient.

Your question may have been tagged to be closed, because "best" is to be avoided in StackExchange.
According to a search for "efficiency of hydraulic pump and motor," one can expect a best case of 82 percent. A similar search for "efficiency of bicycle chain," the numbers are close to 98 percent on a single speed.
Question two is rather vague, while question three cannot be answered without more information.
You mention an engine, which implies internal combustion and the power strokes/pulses. One can mitigate those with a centrifugal clutch, but one will lose efficiency in the process. With ICE systems, efficiency is rarely a factor. I mention the power pulses, as it is common to destroy a chain drive without some means of dealing with them when it is powered by a fueled combustion drive.
A 45 to 1 set of sprockets would be interesting, as you'd have to have at minimum 12 teeth on the drive sprocket and 540 teeth on the driven side. Big honkin' sprocket!
Consider to edit your question to focus on a single aspect, such as efficiency (or not) or transmission types. You did get close, just too many questions with minimal focus.

Thank you for the response. I will edit the question so that it is more direct.
